# How to get object in different translations with Doctrine and Gedmo Translatable Extension

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, translate

I'm stuck with the following problem: I want to fetch doctrine entities of a specific locale without breaking the default behavior of my Symfony app.

Here is an example of one of my entity:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ProductRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     */
    protected $name;

    // ...
}
```

The a part of related doctrine repository:

```
class ProductRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function findOneProductInLocale($id, $locale)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('p')
            ->where('p.id = :id')
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->setParameter('id', $id);
        ;

        $query = $qb->getQuery();

        $query->setHint(
            \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER,
            'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker'
        );

        // force Gedmo Translatable to not use current locale
        $query->setHint(
            \Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener::HINT_TRANSLATABLE_LOCALE,
            $locale
        );

        $query->setHint(
            \Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener::HINT_FALLBACK,
            1
        );

        return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

and a part of my scripts:

```
// default Locale: en
// request Locale: de
$repo = $em->getRepository('Acme\\Entity\\Product');

$product1 = $repo->findOneById($id);
echo $product1->getName(); // return 'Name (DE)'

$product_de = $repo->findOneProductInLocale($id, 'de');
echo $product_de->getName(); // return 'Name (DE)';

$product_en = $repo->findOneProductInLocale($id, 'en');
echo $product_en->getName(); // return 'Name (EN)'

echo $product1->getName(); // return 'Name (EN)' instead of 'Name (DE)' !! <-- What is wrong?

// even if I refetch a product
$product2 = $repo->findOneById($id);
echo $product2->getName(); // return 'Name (EN)' without taking anymore in account the current locale
```

Is someone now why this didn't work as expected ?
Is something wrong in my implementation of `ProductRepository::findOneProductInLocale()` ?

Any help or hint is welcome.

Comment: Because you have set the fallback in Product Repository! `$query->setHint(
            \Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener::HINT_FALLBACK,
            1
        );`  here 1 signifies fallback to default locale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm kind of late with my answer, but I face the same issue & found a solution. I hope it will help some other developers.

1. Your `findOneProductInLocale` if perfectly fine.

   **It works as design** - when you will use `findOneProductInLocale`, **the query will search in the given locale**, but the **final entity will always be loaded in the current locale**, you can't change it.
2. Once the **entity has been found** via `findOneProductInLocale` & **loaded in the current locale**, you can get the locale variant you need by using `setTranslatableLocale` method of Gedmo & refreshing your entity as explain by [@umadesign](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393822/umadesign)

   ```
   // Reload the entity in different languages.
   $entity->setTranslatableLocale($locale);
   $em->refresh($entity);
   ```
3. (Optional) You may need to add the `setTranslatableLocale` method & the companion property `$local` to your translatable entity

   ```
   class Product {
     // ...

     /**
       * @Gedmo\Locale
       * Used locale to override Translation listener`s locale
       * this is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property
       */
     private $locale;

     /**
       * Set the locale to use for translation listener
       *
       * @param string $locale
       *
       * @return static
       */
     public function setTranslatableLocale($locale) {
         $this->locale = $locale;
         return $this;
     }

     // ...
   }
   ```

You can find the complete explanation in the [Gedmo documentation under "Basic usage examples" subsection](http://atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/doc/translatable.html#basic-usage-examples).

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the entity should restore the current locale:

```
$em->refresh($product1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your `$product1`, `$product_de`, `$product_en` and `$product2` are all the same. If you `var_dump` them, they have the same `object #id`. They refer to the same `Product Entity`. If you change anything in one, it is changed in all of them. To have them distinct, you have to `clone` them.

```
$product_de = clone $repo->findOneProductInLocale($id, 'de');
$product_en = clone $repo->findOneProductInLocale($id, 'en');
```